# BottombarNavigationView is not working in kitkat

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, bottomnavigationview

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_bar" />
```

app level gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

     /*splits {
         abi {
             enable true
             reset()
             include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
             universalApk false
         }
     }*/
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "user.com.hlthee"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
    }
}
```

Theme

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="background">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/myDialog</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/myDatePickertheme</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/itemTextStyle.AppTheme</item>
        <item name="itemTextAppearance">@style/itemTextStyle.AppTheme</item>
    </style>
```

It is working perfectly fine in api level greater or equal to 21 but it is not working in kitkat. I have even try with the other library but the output is same. I am exactly getting what is the problem with my code.

Comment: Please provide error log, Or you can follow this demo, it working great.
https://github.com/segunfamisa/bottom-navigation-demo

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I am not getting any error log, then how will I provide.